# Is there a high-order function to convert a linked list to an array?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Imagine I have a simple linked list:

```
class Node {
  var parent: Node?
}


// Create the chain: a <- b <- c
let a = Node()
let b = Node(parent: a)
let c = Node(parent: b)
```

Now I want to convert `c` into an array (`[c, b, a]`)  so I can use other high-order functions like map.

What is a method that produces an array from a linked list typically called?

Is there a way to use other high-order functions to implement this and not use a loop?

---

The only implementation I could think of falls back to using a loop:

```
func chain<T>(_ initial: T, _ next: (T) -> T?) -> [T] {
  var result = [initial]
  while let n = next(result.last!) {
    result.append(n)
  }
  return result
}

chain(c) { $0.parent } // == [c, b, a]
```

I'm wondering if there is a built-in way to use functions like map/reduce/etc. to get the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sequence(first:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence) to make a `Sequence` and then [`Array()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2907560-init) to turn that sequence into an array:

```
let result = Array(sequence(first: c, next: { $0.parent }))
```

or equivalently:

```
let result = Array(sequence(first: c, next: \.parent))
```

You could use it to implement `chain`:

```
func chain<T>(_ initial: T, _ next: @escaping (T) -> T?) -> [T] {
    Array(sequence(first: initial, next: next))
}
```

But I'd just use it directly.

**Note:**  If you just want to call `map`, you don't need to turn the sequence into an `Array`.  You can just apply `.map` to the sequence.

For example, here is a useless `map` that represents each node in the linked list with a `1`:

```
let result = sequence(first: c, next: \.parent).map { _ in 1 }
```

Comment: or simply `sequence(first: c, next: \.parent)`

Answer (score 2):

You could make `Node` be a "denaturated" sequence, this will automatically bring all high-order functions: `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `flatMap`, etc.

```swift
class Node {
    var parent: Node?
    var value: String
    
    init(parent: Node? = nil, value: String = "") {
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = value
    }
    
}

extension Node: Sequence {
    struct NodeIterator: IteratorProtocol {
        var node: Node?
        
        mutating func next() -> Node? {
            let result = node
            node = node?.parent
            return result
        }
    }
    
    func makeIterator() -> NodeIterator {
        NodeIterator(node: self)
    }
}


// Create the chain: a <- b <- c
let a = Node(value: "a")
let b = Node(parent: a, value: "b")
let c = Node(parent: b, value: "c")

// each node behaves like its own sequence
print(c.map { $0.value }) // ["c", "b", "a"]

print(b.map { $0.value }) // ["b", "a"]
```